# GitLab CI and Distributed Build Confusion

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm relatively new to continuous integration servers. I've been using GitLab (v6.5) for a while to manage projects, but I'd like to begin using the GitLab CI to ensure tests pass and builds succeed.

My testing setup consists of two virtual machines: one machine for GitLab and another machine for the GitLab CI (and runners). However, in production I only have a single machine, which is running GitLab. The GitLab team posted an [interesting blog post](https://about.gitlab.com/2013/06/20/integrating-gitlab-ci-with-gitlab/) a while back that emphasized:

> If you are running tests on the CI server you are doing it wrong!

It was a very informative post, but I didn't come away feeling like I understood this specific point. Does this mean one shouldn't run GitLab and GitLab CI on the same server? Does it mean one shouldn't run GitLab CI and GitLab CI runners on the same server? Or both-- Do I need three servers, one for each task?

From the same post:

> Anybody who can push to a branch that is tested on a CI server can easily own that server.

This implies to me that the runners are the security risk since they can run stuff contained in a commit. If that's the case, what's the typical implementation? Put GitLab and GitLab CI on the same machine, but the runners on a separate machine? Wouldn't it still suck if the runner machine was compromised? So people are okay losing their runner machine as long as their code machine is safe?

I would really like to understand this a bit more-- definitely before I implement it in production. Is there any possible yet safe way to implement GitLab, GitLab CI, and GitLab CI runners all on the same machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally you're fine running gitlab-ci and gitlab on the same host. Others may disagree with me but the orechestrator (the gitlab-ci node) doesn't do any of the heavy lifting. Its strictly job meta IO and warehousing the results.

With that being said, I would *not* put the runners on the same machine. Gitlab-CI Runners are resource intensive and will be executing at full tilt on whichever machine you place them on. Its a good idea if you're running in production to put these on spot instances to help curb some of the costs of running the often cpu/memory hungry builds  - but can be impractical as your instances are not always on at that point.

I've had some success with putting my gitlab-ci runner's in digital ocean on small instances. I'm not doing HUGE builds, but the idea is to distribute the work load against several servers so your CI server:

- Is responsive
- Can build multiple project builds at once
- Can exercise isolation (this is kind of arbitrary in this list)

and a few other things that don't come to mind right away.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate the response! Yeah, GitLab CI itself really just seems to be a web front-end, so it makes sense that the runners are really what the blog entry referenced in the original post were referring to.